# Counting through an array of hashes

Tags: ruby

I have this array of hashes:

```
[
  {"name": "John doe","job": "construction"}, 
  {"name": "mary","job": "cook"}
  ...
]
```

I am supposed to count how many people there are with the same name. If there are five `"mary"`s, I should have `5`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What code have you tried so far?  What error message(s) did you get?

Comment: When you given an example please include only valid Ruby objects. Here that would mean no "...". Also give the desired return value for your example as another valid Ruby object.  It is also helpful to assign a variable to each input object, so readers can refer to those variables in answers and comments without having to define them. Here that might be `arr  = [{ name: "John doe", ...]` and `person = "mary"`. You would then say that you want to determine the number of values of `:name` in all the elements of `arr` that equal the value of `person`.

Comment: `{ "name": "cat" }`, `{ name: "cat" }` and `{ :name=>"cat" }` are all equivalent, so there is no point in using the first of these. The only time you would want to do that is when the symbol is made up of two or more words, such as ` { "cat lives remaining": 4 } #=> {:"cat lives remaining"=>4}`.

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mcve].

Comment: Can you provide a *precise* specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases?

Comment: "I am supposed to count how many people there are with the same name." – You do it by writing a program which does that. If you have a problem with your program, carefully read the documentation of all the methods, classes, modules, and libraries you are using, write tests for your programs, trace the execution with pen and paper, single-step it in a debugger, then sleep on it, start again from the beginning, sleep on it again, and *then and only then* ask a focused, narrow question on [so].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how specific your match has to be the following would do a case insensitive match on the "Mary"s assuming `users` contains the array in your question.

```
users.count { |user| user['name'] =~ /mary/i }
```

See the documentation for [Enumerable#count](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-count). The third form will take a block that will result in the number of items for which the block returns true.

In my example, we're accessing the `'name'` key of each hash and comparing it to a case insensitive match against the regular expression `/mary/`. [The `=~` operator](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-3D-7E) returns the integer value of the first match (a truthy value) or `nil` if it does not match which is a falsey value.

Hopefully this answers your question and the components of the answer with documentation.

Comment: this is what did it, thank you so much!!!!!!!!!!! your help means the world to a newbie like me

Comment: I believe you mean `user[:name] =~...`. I wasn't aware that  `nil =~ regex  #=> nil` (because `nil.method(:=~).owner #=> Kernel`).

Comment: @marcoalvarez Glad it helped. Ruby is a great language not only to learn how to program but to use everyday. I'd highly recommend Sandi Metz's book Practical Object-Oriented Design in Ruby to go from newbie to novice in 1.0 books.

Comment: @CarySwoveland In Marco's example it looks the keys are strings and since I can't guarantee a `HashWithIndifferentAccess` I decided to use the syntax that would be sure to succeed.

I also love it when Ruby _just works_. It's such a great language for developers because it's so simple to write if you put the effort in and yet so powerful in what you can do with it. `Kernel` and `Object` are worth checking out for anyone reading this as you'll get such a great idea of what you can expect in Ruby.

Comment: With `users` defined as the OP has (without `...`), `users
 #=> [{:name=>"John doe", :job=>"construction"}, {:name=>"mary", :job=>"cook"}]` shows the keys are symbols. `users.count { |user| user['name'] =~ /mary/i } #=> 0`, whereas `users.count { |user| user[:name] =~ /mary/i } #=> 1`. Notice this is a pure-Ruby question, so Rails' `Class Object::HashWithIndifferentAccess < Hash` doesn't apply

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
  name_count = Hash.new(0) # default count of same name: 0
  users = [
     {"name": "John doe","job": "construction"}, 
     {"name": "mary","job": "cook"}
  ]
  users.each do |user|
    name_count[user[:name]] += 1
  end
  puts name_count
```